# websockets, updating div with messages from server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

```
websocket.onmessage = function (evt) { 
    console.log('Retrieved data from server: ' + evt.data); 
    $('#someDiv').append(evt.data);
};
```

If i open 2 tabs in my browser, why does this event only fire in the active tab that i send the message from? Since the data is recieved from the server, shouldnt this fire in both tabs simultaneously?

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    // You should not use autoAcceptConnections for production
    // applications, as it defeats all standard cross-origin protection
    // facilities built into the protocol and the browser.  You should
    // *always* verify the connection's origin and decide whether or not
    // to accept it.
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
  return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
      // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
      request.reject();
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
      return;
    }

    var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        if (message.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
            connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
        }
        else if (message.type === 'binary') {
            console.log('Received Binary Message of ' + message.binaryData.length + ' bytes');
            connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
        }
    });
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try opening it in two browsers?  browsers will typically limit the number of web socket connections to a single domain, so the 2nd tab probably doesn't connect.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Yea, ive tried that already :/. I see "connection accepted" for both of my tabs in the server. Thanks though

Comment: What does your server-side code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each tab/window opens own websocket with own identifier and your server should send messages to all websockets opened by current user.

In your case when you're sending the messages only to first connected websocket you can share the data between tabs/windows on same domain using [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage) as messages buffer. [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) could help you to put objects to localStorage and retrieve them, and also ensure cross-browser compatibility). Then set an interval for function invocation which will look for new messages periodically.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If i use your localstorage option i might as well skip the websocket part completly, since it would work just as fine without it. On all online examples i can connect and chat with myself from multiple tabs, whats the difference in my code?

Comment: Do you use this library to deal with websockets https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/ ?

Comment: I think that im only using node.js atm. How would i install, for example, socket.io?

Comment: Then look to http://socket.io/#how-to-use, namely the example with socket.on('set nickname', ... You can same set user_id after connection and keep all user's sockets in collection like {user1_id:user1_sockets, user2_id:user2_sockets/*, etc...*/}, then broadcast/emit message to all user's sockets.

Comment: Hmm, im getting an error when using `npm install socket.io`: http://pastebin.com/xKudGqYy . Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Log says:

`**49 error Error: 404 Not Found**
49 error     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\fetch.js:47:16)
49 error     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
49 error     at WriteStream.flush (fs.js:1514:12)
49 error     at fs.close (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:92:5)
49 error     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)`

looks like it tried to download some source files from somewhere but that server didn't answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how it goes with Windows since I'm working in Linux and have no such troubles. :/

Comment: There were some other questions on SO last night that indicated that the NPM repository was throwing 404's around; try again today and see what you get. :)